# Trigger of Batch Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers, batch-updates

I have 3 tables and a trigger in the Purchase table.

User (UserId | Balance)

Purchase (PurchaseId | UserId | Amount | IsConfirm)

TransactionDetail (TrxId | UserId | Balance |Amount)

When the Purchase IsConfirm is updated from False to True, I want the trigger to update Player Balance and insert new record(s) into TransactionDetail.

I have this bulk update statement:

UPDATE Purchase SET IsConfirm = true WHERE UserId=1

I know that trigger will only be fired once for a batch update. 
So if there are 5 rows updated, there is only 1 row inserted into the TransactionDetail table, and the balance is not updated correctly.

If there are 5 rows affected in a batch update,
by using trigger, is there any way to insert 5 updated rows into the TransactionDetail and update the user balance correctly?

Comment: sure, check the inserted and deleted pseudo tables inside the trigger. or, even better, stay away from the triggers..

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't store *calculated* data (such as the user's balance, here) in a database, unless there's a specific performance reason to do so (and often, even then, you can get SQL Server to do the hard work of *maintaining* that data). It's just an invitation for the calculated data to get out of sync with reality. If you always just access the `SUM(Balance)` (or `Amount`, bit confusing having both in the transaction table) then you'll always get the correct value.